# How do you include a class into the runtime environment when a custom classloader loaded the class?

Tags: java, classloader

I'm sure this seems obvious to most java programmers -- and I "think" I know the answer, but my issue is that I need to use a custom class loader. I'd like to use the custom class loader and still be able to use the classes in my code as I would any included class.

Example:

```
// returns my class loader -- set earlier on the thread.
ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
Class loadedVersion = Class.forName("org.example.MyClass"); // works
// loadedVersion's class loader is also equal to cl

// generates "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" at runtime on the following line
org.example.MyClass m = new org.example.MyClass();
```

How would I go about doing this so I can have the class loaded using the custom class loader, and still be able to use my classes "plainly" in the editor?

Edit: The revised title is misleading -- the classes *load* just fine. As indicated in my original post. The issue, my understanding, is that I am currently unable to use the classes in regular declaration statements (in the editor as I would use any java.* classes).

**Update, I hope this better explains what I'm trying to do.**

```
// set the thread's class loader
ClassLoader cloader = new MyClassLoader(); // internal mess to load bytecode omitted
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(cloader);

// This works:
Method m = cloader.loadClass("my.SuperClass").getMethod("doStaticMagic", new Class<?>[] {});
m.invoke(null, null);

// This does not work:
my.SuperClass.doStaticMagic(); // NoClassDefFoundError
```

This is the "issue". I want to use my classes "plainly" (I really don't know the right word) in the editor. I don't want to have to load each individual method -- isn't that what the classloader is for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution (answer) to my original question. I still don't consider this ideal, but this does work.

I created a "bootstrap" application that first loads all the custom 3rd party jars, and then loads and calls my application class. This way I get auto-complete and source hints for the 3rd party jars.

I hope this helps someone, or invites further comments.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you have only interface on classpath and loading the implementation by classloader or whatever, As in the code below:

```
Class loadedVersion = Class.forName("org.example.MyClass"); 

IMyClass m = (IMyClass)loadedVersion.newInstance();
```

where IMyClass is the interface which is implemented by `org.example.MyClass`.
In this way you can absolutly decouple the implenetations of your classes from the client code

**EDIT**

`NoClassDefFoundError` is also arised when you have an exception while initializing static variables or executing static block initializer. Check youe class, maybe it throws such exceptions.

Comment: Would this really make sense if, say, I had a "lot" of classes that would be loaded?

Comment: On the one hand you don't want to be coupled with implementation details, but on the other - you want to load a lot of different classes dynamically. I think, it's a good reason to redesign your solution, maybe you don't need these classes to be dynamically loaded...

Comment: I admit it is a design "flaw", but it is not my own. I'm using a 3rd party library, and successfully using their class loader. I like your answer, but it doesn't get me where I "want" to be. I'm obviously not highly proficient with java classloaders.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the [newInstance() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29). Since you have the "Class loadedVersion", you can use it to call the method.

Comment: @aetheria I want to be able to load my classes with the custom loader, then just use them in my editor as I would any other class declaration.